# Have POE based IRC bot display text every hour

Tags: perl, bots, irc, poe

I have a POE based IRC bot that uses "modules" for command sets. The core bot script loads *.pm files in the plugins directory of the bot's home directory.

I want to have one module that can read a config and send xxx text to xxx channel(s) every xxx minutes. But it has to be launched in the background so that loading modules can continue.

I have done a while(1) loop but as long as the loop is active, the module cannot continue and I cannot send commands to it.

I am looking for a way to basically launch a sub into the background, keep track of its pid, and be able to stop it at will.

The bot's architecture is:

bot.pl loads bot.pm which is the main module. bot.pm loads *.pm files which live in the plugins directory. A plugin can contain or more more bot commands.

Answer (score 0):

Is this based on Bot::BasicBot or Bot::BasicBot::Pluggable?  If so, you can give your module a tick method that will be called however often you want.

Comment: POE::Component::IRC.. the rest I have done on my own.